# To display image inside panel

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have a image i want to place the image inside the panel But image takes whole page to display but i want to display in a panel pls help me to do this.

```
if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
                    docimg.ImageUrl = "C:\\Search\\" + strName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\" + Imgdocname;

                    docimg.Visible = true;
                    Response.WriteFile(docimg.ImageUrl);
}


<div ID="imgContainer" runat="server" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;  overflow:auto; border: solid 1px black;
                    padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;" >
                    <asp:Panel ID="imgPnl" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="docimg" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px"/></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: What issue/error are you seeing? when does this code get called?

Comment: @christiandev The image is taking the whole page to display i want to display in a panel.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are reading an image from `C Drive` physical path in a server and loading the image in the entire response.

I would suggest you to do the following

1. Copy the image into your web app directory
2. Just assign the new relative url

Below is the p-sedo code

```
if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
{
     string imagePath= "C:\\Search\\" + strName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\" + Imgdocname;
     //Read image from location and save it in the web application
     string savedTempPath="/temp/Imgdocname.jpeg";

     docimg.ImageUrl=Server.MapPath("~/temp/Imgdocname.jpeg");

}
```

**Better Approach**

The better approach would be use an handler/seperate page to process for you

***ImageProcess.aspx***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 string imageName=Request.QueryString["fName"];
 // then more logic on file extn etc

 if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg")
 {
  Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
  string file = "C:\\Search\\" + strName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\" + Imgdocname;
  Response.WriteFile(file);
 }

}
```

In aspx

```
<div ID="imgContainer" runat="server" >
 <asp:Panel ID="imgPnl" runat="server">

   <asp:Image ID="docimg" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl="~/ImageProcess.aspx?fName=test.jpeg" 
     Width="100px" Height="100px"/>
  </asp:Panel>
 </div>
```

Comment: But i have more than 1000 images in C drive so i want to access from C drive if i have in web app directory will it have enough space to hold

Comment: how to display inside a panel

Comment: @user3580909, you want me to do a copy paste also for you? anyway updated